# Get the first day and last day of Previous month using SYS.ANYDATA.CONVERTDATE

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I want to get the first day and last day of the previous month using `SYS.ANYDATA.CONVERTDATE(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM'))` as it allows me to use the date in my job chain script only by converting the date using `SYS.ANYDATA.CONVERTDATE`.

In the `ARGUMENT_NAME`for `IN_DATE_FROM_DTS`  i want to put the first day of the previous month date in `DEFAULT_VALUE` parameter. In the `ARGUMENT_NAME`for `IN_DATE_TO_DTS`  i want to put the last day of the previous month date in `DEFAULT_VALUE` parameter.

```
SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.DEFINE_ANYDATA_ARGUMENT(
        PROGRAM_NAME => 'TST_PW',
        ARGUMENT_NAME => 'IN_DATE_FROM_DTS',
        ARGUMENT_POSITION => 7,
        ARGUMENT_TYPE => 'DATE',
        DEFAULT_VALUE => ''
        );
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.DEFINE_ANYDATA_ARGUMENT(
        PROGRAM_NAME => 'TST_PW',
        ARGUMENT_NAME => 'IN_DATE_TO_DTS',
        ARGUMENT_POSITION => 8,
        ARGUMENT_TYPE => 'DATE',
        DEFAULT_VALUE => ''
        );
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure In understand what you're trying to do or why; bu you haven't said what problem you are having - so you get an error from what you showed, or if you try to replace the `''` with the `convertdate` call, or something else? An MCVE might help.

Comment: actually i did not convert date before using SYS.ANYDATA.CONVERTDATE and in my job chain script i have to convert date using SYS.ANYDATA.CONVERTDATE and get the first day of previous month and last day of previous month and set the into default_value parameter in script..

Comment: So i just need to modify the condition SYS.ANYDATA.CONVERTDATE(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM')) such that it will get the first date and last date of previous month but i dont know how to do that ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i just need to modify the condition SYS.ANYDATA.CONVERTDATE(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM')) such that it will get the first date and last date of previous month

So really you're just asking how to get the first and last day of the previous month, instead of the first day of the current month that you get with `TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM')`.

You can use the `add_months()` and `last_day()` functions. To see the first and last day of the current month you can use:

```
select sysdate as raw_date,
  trunc(sysdate, 'MM') as first_of_month,
  last_day(trunc(sysdate)) as last_of_month
from dual;

RAW_DATE            FIRST_OF_MONTH      LAST_OF_MONTH      
------------------- ------------------- -------------------
2018-09-18 10:30:33 2018-09-01 00:00:00 2018-09-30 00:00:00
```

And for the previous month:

```
select add_months(sysdate, -1) as raw_date,
  trunc(add_months(sysdate, -1), 'MM') as first_of_month,
  last_day(trunc(add_months(sysdate, -1))) as last_of_month
from dual;

RAW_DATE            FIRST_OF_MONTH      LAST_OF_MONTH      
------------------- ------------------- -------------------
2018-08-18 10:30:33 2018-08-01 00:00:00 2018-08-31 00:00:00
```

As `anydata` you can then use:

```
sys.anydata.convertdate(trunc(add_months(sysdate, -1), 'MM'))
sys.anydata.convertdate(last_day(trunc(add_months(sysdate, -1))))
```

so:

```
select sys.anydata.convertdate(trunc(add_months(sysdate, -1),'MM'))  as first_of_month,
  sys.anydata.convertdate(last_day(trunc(add_months(sysdate, -1)))) as last_of_month
from dual;

FIRST_OF_MONTH()
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LAST_OF_MONTH()
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ANYDATA()
ANYDATA()
```

Converting back to actual dates for display:

```
select sys.anydata.convertdate(trunc(add_months(sysdate, -1), 'MM')).accessdate()
    as first_of_month,
  sys.anydata.convertdate(last_day(trunc(add_months(sysdate, -1)))).accessdate()
    as last_of_month
from dual;

FIRST_OF_MONTH      LAST_OF_MONTH      
------------------- -------------------
2018-08-01 00:00:00 2018-08-31 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

this will work for previuos months:

```
select trunc(add_months(sysdate,-1), 'MM'),last_day(add_months(sysdate,-1)) from dual;
```

sample output:

```
01-08-18    31-08-18
```

for getting day it will be:

```
select TO_CHAR((select trunc(add_months(sysdate,-1), 'MM') from dual), 
'DAY') ,TO_CHAR((select 
last_day(add_months(sysdate,-1)) from dual), 'DAY')from dual;
```

sample output:

```
WEDNESDAY   FRIDAY
```

Comment: as i mentioned before in my job chain script it will take only converted date using SYS.ANYDATA.CONVERTDATE so this will not work there

Comment: So i just need to modify the condition SYS.ANYDATA.CONVERTDATE(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM')) such that it will get the first date and last date of previous month but i dont know how to do that ..

Comment: `sysdate-30` isn't safe; if you run that in the first couple of days in March you'll January dates, rather than February. And if you run it on the 31st of January, March, July etc. you'll get dates for the current month rather than the previous one.

Comment: @AlexPoole the we can use add_months in neagtive.

Comment: @AlexPoole select TO_CHAR((select trunc(add_months('01-03-2018',-1), 'MM') from dual), 'DAY') ,TO_CHAR((select 
last_day(add_months('01-03-2018',-1)) from dual), 'DAY')from dual; check this its working output is THURSDAY  WEDNESDAY  which is correct

Comment: Yes, I know `add_months()` works - I used that in my own answer. But I'm not sure why you've chosen to show the day of the week instead of the actual dates generated; or why you're using subqueries, e.g. `select to_char(trunc(add_months(sysdate,-1), 'MM'), 'DAY'), ...`. (And it may not matter but your `last_day()` result will have the current time).